# How to unbind event on SVG element

Tags: svg

As in topic, how to unbind i.e click event on svg element? Click event is added by "on()" function on the element.

```
$(e.element).unbind('click');
e.element.removeEventListener();
```

Seems to also not working.

Comment: Have you tried `$(e.element).on("click", null)`?

Comment: I tried, it also not work, later I will try full example

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (I've posted my own jsfiddle in my answer), Could you provide a JSFiddle where to reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The unbind method works Ok with jQuery, I've created a JSFiddle that shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/sPJqN/

My JS Code:

```
$('#r').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});

$('#b').on('click', function() {
     $('#r').unbind('click');
});
```

The HTML code:

```
<button id="b">Remove listener</button>
<svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" id="r" />
</svg>
```

So, I suspect, that the problem is your object `e.element`, If you post some more code, maybe the root cause would be identified.